# Copying database from RES folder to local database in Google Nexus One in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on an Android application in which on app start-up I copy the database from RES folder to local database making an SQLite database for the app. Its working fine in every other device and in all OS version except HTC Google Nexus One device.
I am asking this issue second time because I am trying to discover the solution by a different way.
 I am using the below code for copying the database to local db.

```
public class ECatalogueDatabase {

    private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.weg.ecatalogue/databases/";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ECatalogue";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "T_Electrical";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String KEY_ROWID="id";
    public static final String KEY_PRODUCT_LINE="productline";

    public static final String KEY_VOLTAGE="voltage";
    public static final String KEY_OUTPUTHP="outputhp";

    public static final String KEY_FRAME="frame";
    public static final String KEY_RPM="rpm";

    private Context context=null;
    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static final String CREAT_DATABASE="Create Table if not exists "+ DATABASE_TABLE+"("+ KEY_ROWID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"
    +KEY_PRODUCT_LINE +" nvarchar ,"+ KEY_OUTPUTHP+" numeric ,"+ KEY_RPM +" nvarchar ,"+KEY_VOLTAGE +" nvarchar ," +KEY_FRAME +" nvarchar"+")";

    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     *
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public ECatalogueDatabase(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }
    //Helper class
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREAT_DATABASE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public ECatalogueDatabase open() //throws SQLException
    {
        try
        {
            db=DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        }catch(Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    public void close()
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        /**
        * CHANGES DONE BY SHAILESH SHARMA TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM OF 2.2 HTC DESIRE IN CLIENT'S WIFE DEVICE :(
        */
        SQLiteDatabase db_Read = null;
        if(dbExist){
        //DO NOTHING IN THIS CASE
        }else{

        db_Read = DBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        db_Read.close();
        }
        //=================================

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }

    }
    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            //db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

        }

        if(db != null){

            db.close();

        }

        return db != null ? true : false;
    }
    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{


        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;


        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);


        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public int getDatabaseCount(){
        int count = 0;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
        if(cursor!=null){
            count = cursor.getCount();
        }
        cursor.deactivate();
        cursor.close();
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728

Comment: Hello Yaqub, thanks for replying, but I am also following the same code, there is not much difference in these two codes....

Comment: Check this sample project, it should work: http://sdrv.ms/N857Wn

Comment: No Yaqub, still its not working in Nexus only....I tried your code with other android devices and they work fine.:(

Comment: Strange, i have tried and it works on ALL Emulators... i don't have "HTC Google Nexus One device".

Comment: yaah, you are right, its working on emulator of every version but only creating problem on google nexus one device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the solution for this problem and at the instant I just want to share this with you all guys.
The Exception which I was getting

```
CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed
Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed
```

It was totally different problem which I was getting only in few devices like HTC Nexus ONE device and it was working in all OS and all other devices.

When we create database we get a table generated automatically named "**android_table**", I deleted that table and recreated that manually in my SQLite manager. via below two steps of query:

```
CREATE TABLE "android_metadata" ("locale" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US')
```

and

```
INSERT INTO "android_metadata" VALUES ('en_US')
```

And after this step when I run the code, I got the surprise before Christmas. My application is working fine now.

All credit goes to my long R & D and this link which I got after so much efforts:

```
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/
```